# Is it possible to make this workflow happen with Triggers?

Tags: apex, trigger, person-accounts

We're trying create a trigger that will fire when a new contact is added to SF (that contact is created via the Hubspot connector). **Is the workflow below possible through triggers / Apex code?** (I'm not specifically asking for code, just to know if this is possible. The code / error I'm currently getting is posted in [another question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60544/is-it-possible-to-create-a-person-account))

**The workflow:**

When a contact is *created* via the Hubspot connector, this should happen:

- Create a person account
- Associate the contact with the Person account
- Create an opportunity associated with the Person account

When a contact is *updated* via the Hubspot connector, this should happen:

- Update some custom properties[1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60544/is-it-possible-to-create-a-person-account) on the Opportunity associated with the Person account
- Update the first name, last name, and email on the Person account

[1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60544/is-it-possible-to-create-a-person-account) This could be a creation of a new value, or the old value could need to be updated.

Is it possible to do this? If not fully possible, then which parts might work?

Comment: Is the Contact you associate with it supposed to become part of the person account or just attached to it?